# How do you calculate the sum of values in ng-repeat per page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

**Issue**

For example: totalImprCount returns the same value on all the pages since it returns the sum from the last page only.

**Expected result**

I would like to display the correct sum for the following for each page:

```
totalImprCount, totalClickCount, totalMediaSpend, and totalAdvertiserSpend
```

**Pagination used**

Angular Utils Pagination:
https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

**In Controller**

```
$scope.pageSize = 20;

// campaignstats is an array of objects

function sum(campaignstats){
            var imprCount, clickCount, mediaSpend, advertiserSpend;
            imprCount = clickCount = mediaSpend = advertiserSpend = 0;
            var statsPerPage = $scope.pageSize;
            if (campaignstats) {
                for (var stats = 0; stats < campaignstats.length; stats++){
                    imprCount += parseInt(campaignstats[stats].impr);
                    clickCount += parseInt(campaignstats[stats].click);
                    mediaSpend += parseFloat(campaignstats[stats].media_spend);
                    advertiserSpend += parseFloat(campaignstats[stats].advertiser_spend);
                    $scope.calcCtr = clickCount/imprCount * 100;
                    if (stats == statsPerPage - 1) {
                        $scope.totalImprCount = imprCount;
                        $scope.totalClickCount = clickCount;
                        $scope.totalMediaSpend = mediaSpend;
                        $scope.totalAdvertiserSpend = advertiserSpend;

                        imprCount = clickCount = mediaSpend = advertiserSpend = 0;
                        statsPerPage += $scope.pageSize;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**In View**

```
<tr class="campaign-stats-total-tr">
        <td class="campaign-stats-total-td">Total</td>
        <td> - </td>
        <td>{{ totalImprCount | number }}</td>
        <td>{{ totalClickCount | number }}</td>
        <td>{{ calcCtr | number:2}}%</td>
        <td> - </td>
        <td>{{ totalMediaSpend | currency }}</td>
        <td>{{ totalAdvertiserSpend | currency }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: where you are getting exact problem ?

Answer (score 1):

How about adding   `ng-init="sumFunction(impr, clickCount, mediaSpend, advertiserSpend)"` to your repeat and creating a resetData function on page changes?

Answer (score 0):

I might have understand you, you would like to keep the additions between pages not only from the last page.

If it is that you might have some luck using $rootScope. This will share between your pages a common scope.